# How to forward multipart MIME emails using POP3 and SmtpClient?

Tags: .net, mime, smtpclient, pop3, openpop

I am setting up to write a small tool to poll a POP3 account, then forward found mail. I'm using the OpenPop.NET library for POP3 access, and will most likely use the .NET `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` classes to forward the mail.

OpenPop.NET gives me a `Message` class, which allows me to save the entire message, i.e. headers and all parts, to a file, but when I want to send the message, I just want a body. Now `Message` has a collection parts, each with their own `Body` property, where `Body` is a byte array. It looks like I can use the `AlternateViews` collection to append each of these parts to a `MailMessage`, but I'm a little worried about encoding issues with byte array to string conversions.

I'm also open to suggestions of other ways to achieve this, but right now the process I'm considering is the only one I know.

Comment: Is thee a way to save just the body as strings?

Comment: @Shaun07776 Each `MessagePart` has a byte array `Body` that I can save as a string, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: did you find a way to convert openpop message to SMTP MailMessage and forward to other IDs?

Comment: @Biswajeet I forget details of how I solved the problem, but I switched from `OpenPOP` to `MailKit`, a hugely usable and powerful library.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code for the **AlternativeView**.

```
 _MailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

            AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_Body, "<(.|\\n)*?>", string.Empty), null, "text/plain");
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body, null, "text/html");

            _MailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
            _MailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Comment: I think this is a bit over-simplified. What if the email has multiple parts?

Comment: The only people who will see the plain-text part of your message are those recipients who have their email client configured to receive text-only email and the antispam content filters looking for some text to balance the images in your HTML message. Everyone else will only see your beautiful HTML email design.

Comment: What if the recipient is reading your email with PINE on a dumb Unix terminal? Not everyone uses Outlook or Thunderbird with HTML rendering support.

Comment: @jstedfast, Or a whole host of automated email clients that depend on reading plain text for automation.